# Given two points (A, B) that define a line and two widths (D1, D2) find the lines that connect each sides of the line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given the line defined by the points A and B in a 2D space and two widths (D1, D2 where D1 > D2), I need to find the points P1..P4 so I can draw the lines L1 and L2.

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZo4p.png)

I've been trying to follow some threads that work with slopes and perpendicular vectors, but got no results so far. I would appreciate some help with that. Thanks!

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that $AP_1=AP_2$?

Comment: Using complex numbers one can write: $P_1=A+\frac{D_1}{2} i \frac{B-A}{|B-A|}$.